# Making a reflection on a glossy object based on each frame of the video

Tags: rendering, texturing

I made some attempts in doing it but all of them didn't look to well and they didn't change with the video.
[image: Effect]

I managed to achieve this. Perhaps someone with more experience could give me some tips on making the effect more realistic?
Another question: how can I add a noise to my render so it looks more grainy in a way bad video does?

Comment: What render engine are you using? Please limit your questions to one question at a time.  Also will you add a bit more detail about how you are getting the reflections.

Comment: @David I am using cycles render, added "environmental texture" in nodes editor and opened the video I was using. then added math "multiply " and used the color output of environment as values. I'm not too familiar with node editing and I made it by intuition so I guess it's not perfect.here is the node tree:
[link](http://i.imgur.com/Y0PBs93.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a glossy object and have it reflect an environment comprised of moving images from a video...

[image]

You don't have to map the reflections into the object, just give it a glossy shader and let it reflect the environment.

It's on the World that you need to map your video image and let it reflect on the ring:

[image]