# How to get realtime reflections from motion tracked video?

Tags: materials, video, tracking, motion-capture, hdri

I wanted to know if there is a way to get realtime reflections from a video, like if I have a motion tracked shot of a balloon festival; Naturally this will have a lot of moving colors so it isn't as simple as having a static HDRI.

Say I have a glossy reflective ball centered on my motion tracked shot set to a video of many people releasing colorful balloons, will it reflect the video or do I need some sort of dynamic HDRI? Is that even possible?

Or do I have to project the video onto a plane and have the sphere reflect that?

Is there any way to do these types of reflections? Thanks

Comment: What did you mean **realtime**? Is rendering things from a filmed video clip count toward it? It will be a *big difference* between static clip and live streaming video input.

Comment: Possible dupicate of: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42233/making-a-reflection-on-a-glossy-object-based-on-each-frame-of-the-video/42374#42374

Comment: Yes a static clip, nothing streamed. How to get the reflections from the video onto a reflective object on my scene but taking into account the fact that the object is motion tracked onto the video scene. Is something like that even possible?